# jQuery cannot get any div css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So i'm trying to get familiar with jQuery, so i've been running some test code, but it looks like jQuery's .css is having some problem? I spent the last 3 hours trying different stuff out... no go. I set my div to have the class Content and then i run the page and resize it to trigger the function.

```
.Content {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  padding-top-width:1px;
  padding: 1px;
};

  <div id="wrapper" class="fullscreen">
     <div id="divContainer" class="Container">
        <div id="divContent" class="Content"> Content </div>
        <div id="divQuery" class="Query"> Query </div>
     </div>
  </div>

$(window).resize(function() {
  var container = $('#divContainer');
  var content   = $('#divContent');
  console.log(content.css('border-left-width'));
  console.log(content.css('padding-top-width'));
  //content.width(container.width()*.6-content.attr('padding'));
});
```

From the console, I get the following:

```
 0px
 (an empty string)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `padding-top-width` should just be `padding-top`.
2. `border-top-width` won't work unless you have a `border-style` (e.g. "solid") - otherwise it's assumed to be "none", i.e. no border, and your `border-width` declarations have no effect.

See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/D2e4N/5/ for a working example.

Comment: Thank you nrabinowitz, just tried yours and Cubed Eye's suggestion, both works.

Answer (score 1):

Hyphinated css properties are camelCase in JavaScript.

so it's borderLeftWidth and paddingLeftWidth. This is because the - is used as a subtraction sign in JS. In non-jQuery JS terms `this.style.paddingLeftWidth` is used because `this.style.padding-left-width` implies subtraction of `left` and `width` from `this.style.padding`

So try:

`console.log(content.css('borderLeftWidth'));`

Comment: That's a good answer for straight Javascript, but not the problem here - I think jQuery accepts both forms. See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/D2e4N/1/

Comment: Thank you Cubed Eye, your code worked as well. However, it is just as nrabinowitz said, jQuery took care of the "-" as well since the following also worked:
     console.log(content.css('padding-top'));